# Download an SVG image

Tags: highcharts, canvg

we are trying to download the svg image as the png and using canvg to convert it into the canvas object.But after download we dont see the image and see the wierd black image and not displayed properly.
can u pls fix the fiddle ?

```
   [http://jsfiddle.net/srikanthsvr82/348sh/415/][1]
```

Comment: Have you seen this example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/offline-download/ ?

Comment: @Sebastian - yeah i have seen that example and implemented that way, but facing an issue. Pls look at [link]http://jsfiddle.net/srikanthsvr82/348sh/426/ there is a white background missing at the bottom. can you please try and get the white background for the bottom legend as well.

Comment: Defaulty it takse gray color, but in SVG you have a rect, with white fill. The problem is that height is not enough, so you can increase it. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/348sh/432/

Comment: thanks ..i resolved the issue by doing the same thing.

Comment: @SebastianBochan the issue is resolved but there was another issue. sometimes the download shows black images and after couple of times it shows up correctly.Do you know why?

Comment: Have you any errors in the console?